# When making an animation how can I get a zooming effect?

Tags: after-effects

I want to add a transition to one of my animations that gives the impression of the camera rushing/zooming towards the animation. Is there a better means of doing this in After Effects than scaling all of the elements onscreen up until they screen is filled?
It's an effect you see in a ton of animated infographic-style videos at the moment, but I am new to After Effects and am not sure about the best way to replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag your composition (in the project window) onto the **Make new Composition** button, everything inside that first composition will be added as one layer in the new composition. Now you can just zoom this one layer!

(Say your original comp. is called **1**. You drag **1** onto the button. Now there will be a **New Composition** comp. with one layer inside. This layer is called **1**.)

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on the **3D** switch for all layers, add a **camera** and a **light**, and ***ACTION***, baby! -)

You should gladly turn on **Motion Blur** to get the effect you are talking about it too...

- ***ACTION*** = animate the camera

Answer (score 1):

Add your text layer, and design it as you wish.

Click the 3D icon on the text layer to make it 3D.

Add a camera to the scene.

Open the cameras "transform" settings, and from there, open the "position" settings.

There are three coordinates, corresponding to X,Y, and Z.

Pull the Z coordinate back a lot.

You will see the text get smaller.

Enable key frames by clicking the stopwatch.

Move forward a couple of seconds on the time line.

Pull the Z coordinate forward a lot, until the text is very close.

Add a second key frame, by clicking the diamond icon.

Make sure motion blur is enabled on the text.

Change the two key frames to "easy ease" mode to make the movement start and end gently, but get faster in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If AE or Premiere has a crop/pan feature for each shot with keyframes? or Track motion control for each track with keyframes? Then you could learn to use this and zoom away.